# Unable to change form size in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a new C# WinForm project on Visual Studio 2017 and at first I wanted to change the form to size. However whenever I tried to change it via dragging the borders or even changing it in the form properties, it gave me this error:

[image]

Only recently I installed the mySQL Workbench that I was to use with C# and apart from that, nothing's been deleted or modified to cause this sort of error. Is there a solution to this error?

Comment: Please share code.

Comment: I'd try to repair VS from Control Panel

Comment: @codelover what? The thing is I got this error when I created a new project and I tried to instantly change form size, so I haven't actually coded anything yet

Comment: It sounds like there is something wrong with your installation. `IOleUndoManager` as the name suggest is a COM interface used to handle undo states (when you resize the form, Visual Studio should be able to undo that, by the undo option of course) but it is not available. Could be - that I can think of: Visual Studio install is corrupted (repair), Visual C runtime corrupted (reinstall), Windows corrupted (`sfc /scannow`), hard disk problem (`chkdsk`), RAM problem (windows memory diagnostic). Also check everything is up to date. Edit: I'm assuming this used to work.

Comment: Did you actually select the `Windows Desktop` toolkit on the VS installation menu?